# Quick and dirty GridView not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, gridview

I need to make a simple asp.net MVC project, which contains a GridView. I managed to get the gridview working, and showing actual data (I have an MS Access database set up), but it seems somehow I got something wrong: although everything shows up just fine, any buttons/links (like page updating, delete, edit, etc) don't do nothing. They just submit the form and refresh the page, but nothing is different.

Could you point me in the right direction? (although I couldn't find anything on google, I'm pretty sure this is a common newbie mistake)

*Note: I know I didn't post any code, but I don't know exactly what code to post. If you need further information, please ask.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you talk about *GridView* I hope you are not referring to [GridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.aspx) because that's not something you should be using in an MVC application.

If you are running MVC 3 you could use the [WebGrid](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/154/Looking-At-The-WebMatrix-WebGrid) helper (which has some limitations) or [MVCContrib Grid](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Grid). There is also the [Telerik Grid](http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-mvc/grid.aspx) which is nice and worth looking at. You also have the possibility of a full client side javascript driven grid such as the [jqGrid jquery Grid plugin](http://www.trirand.com/blog/).

Comment: I _am_ referring to _that_ GridView; why do you say you "hope" I'm not ? Please explain (I'm a complete newbie in C#, ASP and MS technologies in general)

Comment: @Gabi Purcaru, that's a server side control which is used in classic ASP.NET WebForms applications. Server side controls don't work in ASP.NET MVC where you no longer have PostBacks, ViewState, ... things that those controls rely on. In ASP.NET MVC there are Controllers, Models and Views. Views could use HTML helpers, etc... I would strongly suggest you following the tutorials on this site: http://asp.net/mvc

Comment: Thanks a lot! I got it now :)

Answer (score 2):

The ASP.Net GridView will probably work much better for you in a conventional ASP.Net Web Site or Web Application project, which is different from an MVC application.

You have mixed the two kinds of web projects. You have to use MVC techniques in an MVC application, as Darin suggests.

If you are in a hurry and you don't mind changing from MVC to classic ASP.Net, you will probably be able to copy your code onto a new WebForm and get it working as you wish fairly quickly.

Otherwise, you will have to start over with a control intended for MVC.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a jQuery Gridview. You can see one example [here](http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html) and you can see a blog post about it [here](http://www.schnieds.com/2010/01/gridview-in-aspnet-mvc.html).